# Получить картинку с помощью Jquery Ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

Задача следующая получить картинку по имеющейся ссылке, закодировать в base64 и отправить на свой сервер.
Запнулся на получении картинки с сервера, я вижу в отладчике что картинка получена, точнее байты, но ответ на запрос все равно попадает в `fail()` :

```js
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_viewport2.png",
  dataType: 'image/jpg',
  success: function(data) {
    alert("ok");
  }
}).fail(function(XHR) {
  alert("false");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: ? `dataType: 'image/png',`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь сделать кроссдоменный запрос да и ещё по https. 
Самый простой вариант - это создать у себя на странице `<img>` засунуть туда src, а потом вставить в канвас и декодировать. Сама функция есть уже на [stackOwerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript)

```js
function getBase64Image(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas.width = img.width;
    canvas.height = img.height;

    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");

    return dataURL.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg);base64,/, "");

}

  img = document.getElementById('img');
  console.log(getBase64Image(img));
```

```html
<img id="img" src="http://es.biznestext.com/image/cache/catalog/logo.png_crop_211.50632911392404_216.99999999999997-275x275.png" style="display:none">
```

Comment: Ваш код из примера не имеет два return

Comment: @koks_rs, спасибо, что что заметили. Поправил